# Changing the Persistent Store

Tags: ignite

I have changed the persistent store from H2 to MYSQL in the Configs but the ignite instance doesn t start.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more contributor 
    license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work for additional 
    information regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to 
    You under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of 
    the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required 
    by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the 
    License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS 
    OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific 
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<!-- Ignite configuration with all defaults and enabled p2p deployment and 
    enabled events. -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Datasource for sample in-memory MYSQL database. -->

    <!--bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
    </bean-->


    <bean id="mysql-example-db" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg"
        class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default 
            is false. -->

        <property name="gridName" value="SubexClientNode" />
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false" />

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events -->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />

                <!--Cache events -->
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial 
            nodes. -->
        <property name="clientMode" value="true" />
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="joinTimeout" value="60000" />
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!-- Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can 
                        be used instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options 
                        refer to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of 
                        initial nodes. -->
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <!-- <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder"> -->
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->

                                <value>localhost:47500..47509</value>

                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The console gives me only these

```
Mar 10, 2016 2:01:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
Mar 10, 2016 2:01:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper instantiateListeners
INFO: Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
Mar 10, 2016 2:01:38 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@5594a1b5, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6a5fc7f7, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@3b6eb2ec, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@1e643faf, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@6e8dacdf]
```

Considering the default in memory H2 database

Nowhere in the config the bean defining the datasource is used as a refernce.Correct me if i am wrong but from my understanding ,the cache store has a role of only loading data  to and from the cache and does nt deal with selecting the persistent store.How does ignite understand about the persistent store?

Comment: Its Fixed :  <bean id="mysql-example-db"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mytable" />
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
 </bean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache store is responsible for both loading data from the database and read/write-through. See [1] for details.

If `CacheJdbcPojoStore` is used, you can provide the name of the data source Spring bean and the store will pick it up:

```
CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, Person> storeFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
storeFactory.setDataSourceBean("mysql-example-db");
```

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store